# Put all dates in range into an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a date range into an array (see code). I am only able to get one date (current date) into the array which is `21/12/2018`. I want all the dates in the current range including `start` and `currentdate`.

```
Sub calculate
    Dim startdate As Date
    Dim loopdate As Date
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim currentdate As Date
    Dim datearray() As Date

    currentdate = Date

    If currentdate = "20/12/2018" Then
        startdate = currentdate + CDate("00:00")
        currentdate = currentdate + CDate("07:29")
    Else
        startdate = DateAdd("d", -1, currentdate) + CDate("07:30")
        currentdate = currentdate + CDate("07:29")
    End If

    For loopdate = startdate To currentdate
        If loopdate <= currentdate Then
            ReDim Preserve datearray(0 To i)
            datearray(i) = DateValue(loopdate)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean with "all the dates in the currrent range including start and currentdate". Your start date is `21/12/2018 00:00` and your current date is `21/12/2018 07:29`. So what dates shall be in between?

Comment: apologies i changed the code to 20/12/2018

Comment: Always not clear. Now it goes into `Else` if `Date` is `22/12/2018`. Then `startdate` is `21/12/2018 07:30` and `currentdate` is `22/12/2018 07:29`. But then there also are not at least two days in between. So the array will contain one date `21/12/2018` only.

Comment: @Axel Richter. I agree. The 'loop' increments by whole days. If I run the code today then I get: `currentdate` = `22/12/2018 07:29:00` and `startdate` = `21/12/2018 07:30:00`. The `startdate` is less than a whole day (by 1 minunte) than `currentdate`. Hence only one date placed in the array.

Comment: Thank you all i incremented the date by one and was able to  get my required output !